# Any way to disable Slide to Call/Message?

Tags: calls, 5.1-lollipop, system-apps

Is there a way to disable the Slide function to call/Message contacts in Phone on Lollipop 5.1.1?

My phone specs:
SM-G925F
Android Lollipop 5.1.1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried opening dialer then select Menu -> Settings -> Contacts -> uncheck "Swipe to call or send message"?

Comment: Wow, I'm such an idiot. Thank you so much, Aaron Gillion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a hidden option on the newer Samsung devices.

Open Dialer, then select `Menu -> Settings -> Contacts` then uncheck `Swipe to call or send message`.

Hope this helps,